# How to monitor CPU heat inside VM inside ESX?

Tags: virtualization, esxi

Say you have a machine hosting ESX, which you do not necessarily have KVM hooked upto. Not a corporate environment, a single box at home.

Is there a way to monitor the CPU heat on this effectively? Is there a way to place a VM and configure in such a way to be a monitoring station for the (actual physical hardware of ESX) heat?

(DOES NOT have to be inside VM - any method!?)

Thank you

**edit** suppose i rephrase to say, if i insert a windows/linux/etc vm in the esx, and get tools which will measure the cpu temp from the gui there, can i trust the measurement it gives me?

Comment: Ok... I don't really understand your question - from the title, I assumed that you wanted to measure heat from within a virtual machine, then, when I read your question, you stated "Does Not have to be inside VM", so, I assume you mean you just want to know of the host... Now from your edit, I am completely confused on what you want to do... Virtual Machines will be at the same heat as the host.  I do not believe that fan monitoring tools inside a VM will work as I don't think ESX itself virtualises sensors.

Comment: "I do not believe that fan monitoring tools inside a VM will work as I don't think ESX itself virtualises sensors." this was what I was getting at (would cpu temp as shown inside a vm be real information or just bogus because not virtualized...)... so I should need some "remote management card or similar" hw to get it thru vSphere-onlu real accurate way... Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely!

However, this depends on the machine.

If it contains heat sensors in a standard industry accepted form, it is more than likely ESX/Vsphere can access them, along with fan information (see picture below).

Simple log on to vSphere client and click on the server, go to `configuration` > `Health Status`, and you should find the information there.

[image]

If the heat information is not available to ESX, I doubt there is much hope other than if your machine has a remote management card or similar.

To make this information available to a guest, I am not entirely sure - it should be possible via a shell script and scripting something that the guest can access (I have been reading up on it here - http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2011/01/how-to-extract-host-information-from.html ).