# Is it possible to fake a CPU temperature on a virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine

On a virtual machine there is no temperature information for my CPU.

In some case, some software match this temperature 
For experience purpose I need to "mock" a temperature 
How can I do that ? (I'm using virtual box)

Comment: I don think so. In a VM the OS is seeing virtualized hardware only, not the actual hardware.

Comment: It might be helpful to better understand what software you are attempting to use in a virtual machine that needs to get temperature data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify your virtualization product and operating system,
but my answer probably relates to all of them: Not possible.

All virtualization products support a virtual CPU model that was common many
years ago and supported by almost all operating systems at that time,
and there is no way to pass-through the computer's real CPU.

Therefore the VM cannot access the physical CPU (or motherboard) for reading sensors.
Actually, letting the VM break out into the physical machine is an enormous
security risk that no virtualization product could ever allow.

The only possibility I have found is under ESX/Vsphere, as detailed in the post
[How to monitor CPU heat inside VM inside ESX?](https://superuser.com/questions/442041/how-to-monitor-cpu-heat-inside-vm-inside-esx),
but this is probably not relevant for you.